# Implicit barrier vs nowait in case of two successive pragma omp for

Tags: c++, openmp

Looking at the document [here](http://pages.tacc.utexas.edu/~eijkhout/pcse/html/omp-sync.html), the following construct is well defined:

```
#pragma omp parallel          //Line 1
{
#pragma omp for nowait        //Line 3
  for (i=0; i<N; i++)
    a[i] = // some expression
#pragma omp for               //Line 6
  for (i=0; i<N; i++)
    b[i] = ...... a[i] ......
}
```

since

> Here the nowait clause implies that threads can start on the second loop while other threads are still working on the first. Since the two loops use the same schedule here, an iteration that uses a[i] can indeed rely on it that that value has been computed.

I am having a tough time understanding why this would be. Suppose `Line 3` were:

`#pragma omp for`

then, since there is an implicit barrier just before `Line 6`, the next for loop will have values at all indices of `a` fully computed. But, with the `no wait` in `Line 3`, how would it work?

Suppose, `Line 1` triggers 4 threads, `t1, t2, t3` and `t4`. Suppose `N` is 8 and the partition of indices in the first for loop is thus:

```
t1: 0, 4
t2: 1, 5
t3: 2, 6
t4: 3, 7
```

Suppose `t1` completes indices `0` and `4` first and lands up at `Line 6` What exactly happens now? How is it guaranteed that it now gets to operate on the same indices `0` and `4`, for which the `a` values are correctly computed by it in the previous iteration? What if the second `for` loop accesses `a[i+1]`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The material you quote is wrong. It becomes correct if you add `schedule(static)` to both loops - this guarantees the same distribution of indices among threads for successive loops. The default schedule is implementation defined, you cannot assume it to be `static`. To quote the standard:

> Different loop regions with the same schedule and iteration count,
>   even if they occur in the same parallel region, can distribute
>   iterations among threads differently. The only exception is for the
>   static schedule as specified in Table 2.5. Programs that depend on
>   which thread executes a particular iteration under any other
>   circumstances are non-conforming.

If the second for loop accesses `a[i+1]` you must absolutely leave the barrier there.

Answer (score 2):

To me the statement that there is no potential problem in the example is wrong.

Indeed, scheduling will be the same as it is not explicitly defined. It will be the default one. Furthermore, if the scheduling was of `static` type, then indeed, there wouldn't be any issue since the thread that would handle any given data in array `a` inside the second loop would be the same as the one which would have written it in the first loop.

But the actual problem here is that the default scheduling is not defined by the OpenMP standard. This is implementation defined... For the (many) implementations where the default scheduling is `static`, there cannot be any race condition in the snippet. But if the default scheduling is `dynamic`, then, as you notice, a race condition can happen and the result is undefined.

Comment: what if the second loop was like `for(int i = 0, i < N/2; i++)`. How would the allocation be maintained consistently?

Comment: It would not - both loops have to use the same iteration count and same static schedule.

Comment: Exactly as @Zulan said.

Comment: What about the following type of second loop: `for(int i = 1; i < N+1; i++) b[i-1] = a[i-1]` vs `for(int i = 1; i < N+1; i++) b[i] = a[i]`; Both seem to satisfy the standard if I understand it correctly (iteration count is `N`), so, how would the iterations be partitioned ?

Comment: The fact that there is no race condition in your initial example with `static` scheduling isn't just due to identical looping, it is also (as I mentioned) because this is the thread which wrote a data in `a` that reads it subsequently, and it alone. Your second example doesn't follow this rule, and isn't safe.

Comment: The standard uses "logical iterations" for assigning iterations to threads as defined as: "A worksharing loop has logical iterations numbered 0,1,...,N-1 where N is the number of loop
iterations, and the logical numbering denotes the sequence in which the iterations would be executed if a set of associated loop(s) were executed sequentially." So if you shift the loop variable consistently, you are fine.